# How to split up the argument of a complex function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

In my course of control theory they used the following simplification for calculating an argument of a complex function:

$$\large
\begin{array}{l}
=\lim _{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}} \angle\left(\frac{1}{\left(\epsilon e^{j \varphi}\right)\left(2 j+\epsilon e^{j \varphi}\right)}\right) \\
=\lim _{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}} \angle(1)-\angle\left(\epsilon e^{j \varphi}\right)-\angle\left(2 j+\epsilon e^{j \varphi}\right)
\end{array}
$$

I don't understand why these two are equal, what is the general rule for such simplifications?

Comment: What does $\angle$ mean in this context?

Comment: @herbsteinberg it's the sign for calculating for complex argument, so $\angle j = \pi / 2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General formula (note math uses $i$ not $j$).

$$x=\frac{a_1}{a_2\times a_3}$$ where $$a_k=c_k+id_k=r_ke^{i\theta_k}$$ then $$x=\frac{r_1}{r_2\times r_3}e^{(\theta_1-\theta_2-\theta_3)}$$
$$\angle(x)=\angle(a_1)-\angle(a_2)-\angle(a_3)=\theta_1-\theta_2-\theta_3$$

Here $c_k=r_k\cos(\theta_k)$ and $d_k=r_k\sin(\theta_k)$.

Comment: Congratulations for your 10k.

Answer (score 2):

We have the two identities for non-zero complex number $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$
$$\text{Arg}(z_{1}z_{2})= \text{Arg}(z_{1})+\text{Arg}(z_{2}) \pmod {(-\pi, \pi]}$$
and
$$\text{Arg}\left(\frac{z_{1}}{z_{2}}\right)=\text{Arg}(z_{1})-\text{Arg}(z_{2}) \pmod{(-\pi,\pi]}$$

The latter formula was used used once and then the first.